# After establishing L2CAP connection with bt_io_connect api by bluez can we get it's HCI connection Handle ? if yes how?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to pass min_connection_interval and max_connection_interval to the BT controller while connecting with an LE device

But Current implementation is based on  *bt_io_connect* function to connect , by which you can't pass these parameters to lower layer.

So after Connection by *bt_io_connect* I want to use *hci_le_conn_update* to update the connection parameters.

But *hci_le_conn_update* needs connection handle, So how can I get that because, *bt_io_connect* function dosn't return any handle like this.